# Locking/make read only a range of Excel Cells using phpExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

How can one lock or make specific cell or range of excel cells read only using phpExcel or just with php after exporting data to those cells say

from A17:f45?

Answer (score 3):

See section 4.6.26 of the Developer Documentation

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A17:F45')
    ->getProtection()
    ->setLocked(
        PHPExcel_Style_Protection::PROTECTION_PROTECTED
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

before, set protected property for the sheet

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSheet(true);    // Needs to be set to true in order to

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
->getStyle('A17:F45')
->getProtection()
->setLocked(
    PHPExcel_Style_Protection::PROTECTION_PROTECTED
);
```

regards

Comment: It locks whole excel file.